# Word Macro Enabled Document Corruption Issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm having a quite puzzling issue with a Word VBA Application I'm developing for my employer and I'm hoping someone has experienced this issue and knows of a solution as I can't find a cause anywhere.

Approximately every other day that I work on the document (.docm) I save my changes prior to closing the document and when I come back to the file it will not open.  I get stuck on the loading screen and the application hangs.

The only solution I've identified is opening word (not the document) in Safe Mode, closing; and asking a colleague to open the file, save it under a new document name, and send it back to me.

Rebooting doesn't fix the issue and the original file seems to be permanently corrupted for me even though my colleague can open the file.  I've also tried deleting word's document cache in the Microsoft Upload Center to no avail and if I don't follow the exact order of opening word in safe mode on it's own prior to opening the replacement file my colleague sends me the replacement file will not open either and I have to start the process again with a second new file from my colleague.

This happens about 2-3 times a week, thank you in advance!

Comment: Search for and rename Normal.dotm so that Word will generate a new, default Normal.dotm, then see if the problem goes away...

Comment: I deleted the .dotm and I've waited quite a while with no further occurrences of the issue, looks like that solved it - thank you!